# Simple JSON request with cURL to Mochiweb

Tags: json, post, curl, erlang, mochiweb

I have a very simple 'hello world' Mochiweb server (I just started my introduction into it), which takes a JSON request and sends it back:

```
'POST' ->
                case Path of
                    "dummy" ->
                        Data = Req:parse_post(),

                        Json = proplists:get_value("json", Data),

                        Struct = mochijson2:decode(Json),

                        Action_value = struct:get_value(<<"action">>, Struct),
                        Action = list_to_atom(binary_to_list(A)),

                        Result = [got_json_request, Action],

                        DataOut = mochijson2:encode(Result),
                        Req:ok({"application/json",[],[Result]});
```

The thing is that when I try to make a request to it with cURL it fails:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"action":"dummy"}' http://localhost:8080/dummy
```

The Mochiweb log is quite difficult to read, but as I understand the error happens at this line:

```
Json = proplists:get_value("json", Data)
```

I have put a couple of `io:format`s in the code and found out that both `Data` and `Json` variables are `[]` after I make a request with cURL.

On the other hand, when I do a very simple request with cURL:

```
curl -d '{"action":"dummy"}' http://localhost:8080/dummy
```

both Data and Json are `[{"{\"action\":\"dummy\"}",[]}]`, but in that case the line `Struct = mochijson2:decode(Json)` fails.

For some strange reason Mochiweb does not see the JSON data in the POST request in case the header has the "application/json" value.

So, the question is: How do I make a correct POST request with JSON data to a Mochiweb server?

EDIT: `Json` variable has the `undefined` value.

Comment: Unrelated, but list_to_atom is a very dangerous tact to take without ensuring that it's restricted; There are a finite number of atoms which can exist in a particular erlang instance -- even though it's very large.

Comment: Atoms are not garbage collected either, so they exist for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
Data = Req:recv_body(),
Json = mochijson2:decode(Data),
...
```

You should at least ensure method post and the content type ahead of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about POST nor get.
It's about how you post your data to send to your server

When you send a json data to server, you need to make it as key=value

```
 curl -d "key=value" "http://your.domain.com/path"
```

Therefore, if you want to post json as '{"action":"dummy"}', for GET request

```
 curl -d "json='{\"action\":\"dummy\"}'" http://localhost:8080/dummy
```

For POST request as a file,

```
curl -F "json=@filename.json" http://localhost:8080/dummy
```

of course, when you send as a file, you need to read the posted file from the server side.